# What can I do when two libjpeg library conflicts

Tags: dynamic, libjpeg

I provide a dynamic library A to others which depends on libjpeg8. 
However,when others link my lib to their application which happens to depend on libjpeg6,
there are some conflicts resulting in crashing.

the dilemma is that they won't replace libjpeg6 to a higher version,and I have to use new functions in libjpeg8, How can I solve this problem in a single process？

Comment: I am having the same issue between libjpeg and the libjpeg that comes with Qt 4.8.4...

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the symbol conflict, I see 2 options :

- link statically libjpeg,
- inject a namespace in the libjpeg (as configure does not propose such option, it will be an heavy patch).